# Irreducible representations of $S_3$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: representation-theory

I want to calculate irreps of $S_3$ over $\mathbb{R}$. I tried to find first a formula to the dimensions of the irreps and I get $\sum dim_{\mathbb R}\mathbb{C}\cdot dim\pi_i^2=|S_3|$, which says that there are 3 irreps of dimension 1. I know two of them (the trivial one, and the sign permutation), but I don't know how to find the third.

Comment: There are only two nonisomorphic complex irreps of degree $1$, so there certainly can't be more real ones than that. Where did you get this formula from? The other complex irrep is of degree $2$, and can actually also be realised over the reals - think of this group as a dihedral group acting on a triangle.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks! I tried to find first a formula in order to understand how many irrupts there are (apparently I was wrong), there is any such formula? where the field is not algebraically closed?

Comment: For the symmetric group, every irreducible representation over a field of characteristic $0$ can be given over $\mathbb{Z}$, so every complex representation is from a real one.

Answer (score 2):

The number of irreducible real representations is equal to the number of real conjugacy classes of the finite group $G$.
(For more details look at
[Correspondence](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_irreducible_representations_equals_number_of_conjugacy_classes) )

A real conjugacy class of an element $g$ is the union of the conjugacy class of $g$ and its inverse $g^{-1}$.

Now we have to look for the real conjugacy classes of $S_3$:

$$[(12)]=\{ (12), (23), (13)\}$$

$$[(123)]=\{ (123), (132)\}$$

$$[1]=\{1\}$$

This means that you have exactly $3$ irreducible real representations.

The first is the trivial one. The second is the sign one, as you said. The third is the action of $S_3$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that realises the symmetry of the triangle:

$$(123):=\begin{pmatrix}
   cos(\frac{2\pi}{3} ) & -sin(\frac{2\pi}{3}) \\
    sin(\frac{2\pi}{3}) & cos(\frac{2\pi}{3} )
\end{pmatrix},$$

$(12):=$ reflection with respect to the axis $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}x$.

To prove that it is irreducible you have to prove that the inner scalar product in the class function space $CF(S_3)$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that conjugacy classes of the symmetric group are classified by cycle type, so they each are closed under inverses -- hence the number of real irreducible representations equals the number of complex ones.

Comment: @KyleMiller yeah, In this way you can prove that the real and the complex irreducible representations are the same :)